# Is "little does he know" correct?

Tags: grammar, american-english, british-english, tenses, past-vs-present

This expression is usually used in past tense ("little did he know") but can it also be used in present tense?

Comment: Not only is it perfectly OK, there's even a [**song about it**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ZnQQF7ucdM).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why not. The contexts in which you'd use it in the present tense are more limited, but it's perfectly grammatical.

I'd imagine you might use this when recording someone's internal monologue:

> *Little does he know*, thought Verity, *his birthday party will be the best ever!*

Comment: Thank you, MattBecker82. I have seen this used in present tense once--I usually see it in past tense. Before posting my question, I came across another English forum which says that using it in present tense is incorrect (http://www2b.abc.net.au/tmb/Client/Message.aspx?b=11&m=2233&ps=50&dm=1&pd=2&am=2235). I asked because I needed another opinion regarding this just to be sure, and thank you for your answer. I'm going to use it in present tense now. XD

Comment: Hi Li Ann, thanks for the feedback. In the post you linked to, the issue is not with _little does he know_ per se, it's with the whole phrase _Little does he know about the history of the country_ which does not make sense and is verging on ungrammatical.

This is because the phrase _little does he know_ isn't simply another way to say _he knows little_. Rather, it's a stock idiom meaning _he is unaware of_, and would typically be followed by the thing of which the person being referred to (_he_) is unaware.

Comment: Oh. I understand now. Thank you, MattBecker82, for giving a clear explanation about it. You're awesome! :)